# How to get all text inside 'td' tags from 'table' tag on html page using Mechanize gem?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to parse table using Mechanize gem but i don't know how to iterate table.

Answer (score 2):

Mechanize uses [`nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/README_rdoc.html) for parsing HTML, so you should look up the documentation there. Namely, take a look at [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) method.

Here's an example, parsing the current page:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265745/how-to-get-all-text-inside-td-tags-from-table-tag-on-html-page-using-mechaniz'))
table = doc.xpath('//table').first # getting the first table on the page
table.xpath('tr/td').count # getting all the td nodes right below table/tr and counting them
#=> 4
```